# An internal error occurred during: "Update SonarLint binding data from 'myserver". org/sonar/api/batch/Sensor - Eclipse(C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, sonarqube, eclipse-cdt, sonarlint

I am trying to connect with Eclipse to SonarQube Server where is located the Code of the company i am working.
I have corectly installed Sonarlint in my Eclipse. (C++) as i followed the documentation : https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse.
Firstly , i went to Window > Preferences > SonarQube > Servers > Test Connection and is saying that the connection is succesful.
Then , i go to my project explorer , right click > Configure > Associate with SonarQube and when i try to connect with my project i have this problem .

[org/sonar/api/batch/Sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l9Ou.png.)

When i try to configure Sonarqube with my local environment and code , i cannot connect because of this error.

Also , i refer that i confirmed that inside the file myproject/sonar-project.properties in my project are the same with the server.

Additionally, when i go to SonarLint Bindings where i can see the my try to connect , i tried to update it with the same values actually, and i saw the picture below. Probably these errors are correlated but i cannot understand how to solve them.
[SonarConnection Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPHI2.png).

Both problems , make me unable to associate my project with the corresponding in Sonarqube. 
Can you provide me with any help about this?
Thanks in advance,
Aggelos

Comment: Which version of the SonarQube server (+plugins) and SonarLint tool do you use?

Comment: @agarbys I changed the version from 4.0 to 3.6. This helped me to associate the project with Sonarqube Server. But i cannot see anthing in the report until now.
Sonarqube C/C++ Integration for Eclipse 3.5.0.20150804.
Plugins are many but I interested in Sonarlint CDT --> 3.6.0.20186071228.
Thanks in advance, Aggelos

Comment: I think you hit `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonar/api/batch/Sensor`. It means that at least one of your plugins is incompatible with SonarLint. Without full list of the plugins it is impossible to find where is the problem.